# Why is request in NodeJS not responding?

Tags: node.js, request

I want to send data and headers using request (what's below in curl I would like to achieve with request), below is the function `foobar()` where the request is taking place. For some reason the below is wrong, but there are no error messages or warnings. Any thoughts?
request used = https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#custom-http-headers

```
function foobar(a, i, callback){

    var requestOptions = {
      url: 'http://someurl/endpoint',
      headers: {
          'X-ELS-Authentication':'FOO',
          'Content-Type':'application/json',
          'Accept':'application/json'
      },
      data: {
          'xqueryx': "<foo><bar:word path=\""+a+"\">"+i+"</bar:word></foo>'
          'start': 0,
          'count': 100,
          'fields': "*"
        }
    };

    function makeRequest(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        callback(JSON.parse(body));
      }
    }

    request(requestOptions, makeRequest);

}
```

**UPDATE**:
This curl equivalent does work:

```
curl_render = 'curl -H "'+curl_request.headers[0]+'" '+
      ' -H "'+curl_request.headers[1]+'" '+
      ' -H "'+curl_request.headers[2]+'" '+
      " --data '"+JSON.stringify(curl_request.data)+"' "+
      curl_request.url;

  exec(curl_render, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      cb(stdout);
  });
```

Comment: How do you know if there are errors or not? Your callback ignores anything but success codes

Comment: Please include the actual request performed in the question. Are you sure that the endpoint exists and is working properly?

Comment: Thanks for comment both, I've updated with an `exec` and curl example that works.
@E_net4 the request goes correctly, but the server returns that there is no data received.
So `data` looks to be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Always use the first parameter as error in callback.

If the request has no error and the status code is `200`. Your callback function code works, What if there is an error or status code is not 200. You have to handle all the cases.

```
function makeRequest(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    callback(null,JSON.parse(body));
  }
  else{
    callback(error);
  }
}
```